# UIButton is clipping descenders (like lowercase "g")

Tags: uibutton, tvos

I'm building a tvOS app that uses a custom font in `UIButton`.

I've noticed that [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) are getting clipped in both the `.Normal` and `.Focused` `UIControlState`, as you can see in this image:

[image]

I've tried adjusting the `contentEdgeInsets` and `titleEdgeInsets`, but neither fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, as I'm writing the question, I remembered the answer!

One solution: subclass `UIButton` and override the methods `titleRectForContentRect` and `contentRectForBounds`, like so:

```
/// A subclass of UIButton that uses the full bounds of the button for the label (so that text isn't clipped)
public class FullFrameTitleButton: UIButton {
    override public func titleRectForContentRect(contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return contentRect
    }

    override public func contentRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds
    }
}
```

The only other remaining bit: center the title label's text:

```
let button = FullFrameTitleButton(type: .System)
button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
```

Voila! No more clipped descenders:
[image]